# Bloom-filter implementation in Clojure

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, bloom-filter

### Background

[Bloom-filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) is a data structure to which we can insert elements, and check if it already contains a given element. The peculiarity is, that if a `contains` query returns `true`, then it might still be possible, that in fact, this element was not inserted to the filter. (If, on the other hand, it returns `false`, then the element was definitely not inserted previously.)

The implementation consists of a bit-vector of length `n` (originally all bits are `0`), and of `k` hash functions, which map any input value into the range of (`[0...n)`, i.e. `0` inclusive, `n` exclusive). When adding an element, we compute its mapped value for all of the `n` hash functions, and set the corresponding bits to one, in the bit vector. Similarly, when querying if an element was added, we compute the value for all the hash functions and return `true`, if all the corresponding bits are `true`, and `false` otherwise (i.e., if the corresponding bit for at least one function is zero).

### Objectives of the review

While any remark/suggestion is always welcome, I'm mostly interested in the following aspects:

1. Is this a correct implementation of the data-structure, or do you see any flaws?
2. Is there a way to make the implementation more optimal? (E.g. is there an elegant way in `bloom-contains` to jump out of the `reduce` if we encounter a bit not equal to `1`?)
3. Related to the above: is there a way to make this code more idiomatic? (I.e., conforming to Clojure best practices.)
4. Can you think of any missing tests? Or some other edge-cases which are not covered?

### Out of scope

The quality of the hash-functions used for testing is out of scope of this review. (I know there are much better ones, but for now I focused on the data-structure itself.)
However, if you know a way to e.g. better organize them, and avoid repetition (but without making that global!), that would be very appreciated.

### The code

`core.clj`

```
(ns bloom-filter.core)


(defn bloom-create [numbits hash-functions]
      (if (or (nil? numbits) (nil? hash-functions)) nil
          {:bits (vec (repeat numbits 0)) :hash-functions hash-functions}))

(defn bloom-add [bloom-filter value]
      (when-not (nil? bloom-filter) 
      (let [hash-functions (:hash-functions bloom-filter)
            bits           (:bits bloom-filter)
            new-bits (reduce (fn [actual-bits hash-function] (assoc actual-bits (hash-function value) 1)) bits hash-functions)]
      (assoc-in bloom-filter [:bits] new-bits))))

(defn bloom-contains [bloom-filter value] 
      (let [hash-functions (:hash-functions bloom-filter)
            bits (:bits bloom-filter)]
      (reduce (fn [actual-value hash-function] (and actual-value (= 1 (bits (hash-function value))))) true hash-functions)))
```

`core-test.clj`

```
(ns bloom-filter.core-test

(:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
          [bloom-filter.core :refer :all]))

(defn mod7-fun [num] (mod num 7))
(defn always-zero-fun [dontcare] 0)  

(deftest create-test
  (testing "create bloom filter"
    (is (= nil (bloom-create nil nil)))
    (is (= nil (bloom-create 0 nil)))
    (is (= nil (bloom-create nil [])))
    (is (= {:bits [] :hash-functions []} (bloom-create 0 [])))
    (is (= {:bits [0] :hash-functions []} (bloom-create 1 [])))
    (is (= {:bits [] :hash-functions [always-zero-fun]} (bloom-create 0 [always-zero-fun])))
))

(deftest add-test
  (let [empty-filter (bloom-create 7 [])
        single-fun-filter (bloom-create 7 [mod7-fun])
        two-fun-filter (bloom-create 7 [mod7-fun always-zero-fun])]
  (testing "add to bloom filter"
    (is (= nil (bloom-add nil 3)))
    (is (= empty-filter (bloom-add empty-filter nil)))
    (is (= empty-filter (bloom-add empty-filter 10)))
    (is (= {:bits [0 0 0 1 0 0 0] :hash-functions [mod7-fun]}
           (bloom-add single-fun-filter 3)))
    (is (= {:bits [1 0 0 1 0 0 0] :hash-functions [mod7-fun always-zero-fun]}
           (bloom-add two-fun-filter 3)))
)))

(deftest contains-test
  (let [empty-filter (bloom-create 7 [])
        simple-filter (bloom-create 7 [mod7-fun])
        filter-with-element (bloom-add simple-filter 3)]
  (testing "bloom filter contains"
    (is (true? (bloom-contains empty-filter 0)))
    (is (false? (bloom-contains simple-filter 0)))
    (is (true? (bloom-contains filter-with-element 3)))
    (is (true? (bloom-contains filter-with-element 10)))
)))
```

### GitHub repo

[The version in this question.](https://github.com/attil-io/data-structures/tree/56d226eb2cb29dc807691116e3de156eaf66c457/bloom-filter)

Comment: very nice problem statement and question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is a very nice question and problem statement. My review consists mainly of code style improvements buy maybe you will still find it helpful.

#### `bloom-create` function

- Instead of `(if ... nil ...)` you can use `(when-not ... ...)`.
- Argument `hash-functions` is a collection of functions so you should
  write `(empty? hash-functions)` instead of `(nil? hash-functions)`.
  Be aware that this changes the semantics of your program.
- I prefer writing simple argument validation as `assert` expressions.
  Like: `(assert (every? ifn? hash-functions))` and `(assert (number? numbits))`.
- Instead of a vector of zeros you can use `(vector-of :boolean ...)` for
  better performance.
- I think you should make sure that the hash functions no not return a value out of range. You can do this by [composing](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/comp) them with `#(mod % numbits)`.

#### `bloom-add` function

- Instead of `(when-not (nil? bloom-filter) ...) you can write (when bloom-filter ...)`
- You can use [destructuring](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring) to get
  the contents of the `bloom-filter` parameter.
- You should use `(assoc ... :bits ...)` instead of `(assoc-in ... [:bits] ...)`.
- You can use the [thread last](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E)
  macro for organizing the code.
- You can use [transient data structures](https://clojure.org/reference/transients) in the `reduce` to make thinks faster. Unfortunately they do not work with `vector-of` at the moment :(

#### `bloom-contains` function

- It is a nice practice to have your predicate method names end with a [question mark](https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide#pred-with-question-mark)
- You can use [reduced](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduced) to jump
  out of the `reduce` call.
- However you might want to consider using [every?](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/every_q) or [some](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/some) predicate instead of a `reduce`.

#### Test cases

- Your data structure is immutable, therefore you can reuse `empty-filter`, `single-fun-filter` and `two-fun-filter` betweeb your tests.
- In `add-test` you may only check the `:bits` part of the result thus making the test cases shorter.

### Code

```
(defn bloom-create [numbits hash-functions]
  (when-not (or (nil? numbits) (empty? hash-functions))
    (assert (number? numbits))
    (assert (every? ifn? hash-functions))
    {:bits           (apply vector-of :boolean (repeat numbits false))
     :hash-functions (mapv (partial comp #(mod % numbits)) hash-functions)}))

(defn bloom-add [{:keys [hash-functions bits] :as bloom-filter} value]
  (when-not (nil? bloom-filter)
    (->> hash-functions
         (reduce (fn [actual-bits hash-function]
                   (assoc actual-bits (hash-function value) true))         bits)
         (assoc bloom-filter :bits))))

(defn bloom-contains? [{:keys [hash-functions bits]} value]
  (some (map #(false? (bits (% value))))))

(require '[clojure.test :refer :all])

(defn mod7-fun [num] (mod num 7))
(defn always-zero-fun [dontcare] 0)
(def single-fun-filter (bloom-create 7 [mod7-fun]))
(def two-fun-filter (bloom-create 7 [mod7-fun always-zero-fun]))

(deftest add-test
  (testing "add to bloom filter"
    (is (= nil (bloom-add nil 3)))
    (is (= [false false false true false false false]
           (:bits (bloom-add single-fun-filter 3))))
    (is (= [true false false true false false false]
           (:bits (bloom-add two-fun-filter 3))))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed review, @erdos. I [improved the code](https://github.com/attil-io/data-structures/tree/2071c084e3dd4590e7a9477aa589ddbe62f2ea0a/bloom-filter) based on your suggestions. I have some follow-up questions:  What is your opinion on using `assert`s vs `:pre`-conditions?  What is the difference between `apply vector-of :boolean` and simply using `vec`? (Btw, with the latter, also `transient` works :) )  Something is missing from the the `bloom-contains` implementation with `some`. (By adding `hash-functions` as the second parameter it still does not work for me...)

Comment: Another interesting question would be if I can validate that the hash-functions really return numbers between `0` and `N`, where `N` is the number of bits. I think this question is so interesting that [I asked it on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48736837/clojure-check-if-a-function-has-certain-post-or-pre-conditions).